# Django admin datetime input appear different format in Chrome and Safari

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.7

I have a model with DateTimeField in my django project.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

In the admin site, I found that in Safari, when I click "now", the time appear in HH:mm:ss, but in Chrome it is HH:mm.

[image]

How can fix it to make it synchronized across browsers? I prefer to NOT show the seconds, i.e. the format in Chrome.

Comment: Probably has to do more with browser rendering than Django itself. Have you checked the HTML that is being generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome 23 stable on OSX and Linux omits the seconds fields if it is unnecessary, and Chrome 24 beta on Windows also omits it.

Hence this is a Chrome specific behavior, you have to look into the specific nature of Safari and prevent showing of seconds on it.